# Auto-update not executing when I launch my exe - install4j -

Tags: install4j

I have set up Auto-update and launcher integration within my project ( Update with silent version check). In my Launcher integration I select "start automatically when launcher is executed" and select my launcher ( which is an external launcher) from the list of launchers but when I select the launcher from the Start Menu after installation no update screen is displayed.

I get no error and no logs indicating the issue. I have confirmed there are updates available as when I run the updater exe on its own the appropriate update screen is dispalyed showing the version change.

I have selected Launch schedule: Always and Launch mode: Blocking on startup.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong? Is it possible to set auto update with an external launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launcher integration for updaters is only supported for generated launchers. For external launchers, install4j has no hook to insert the auto-update check.

You can call the updater yourself, though. On the "Launcher integration" tab, click on "Start integration wizard" and add the code snippet to your your own code.